# Show the list of exceptions that are thrown by service method

Tags: c#, wcf

How to check the exceptions that are possibly thrown by a service method? Consider the following program

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IApple{
    [FaultContract(typeof(DivideByZeroException))]
    [OperationContract]
    int set(bool val);
}
public class Apple : IApple{
    public int set(bool val)
    {
        throw new FaultException<DivideByZeroException>(new DivideByZeroException());
    }
}

Client.cs
----------
Main(){
   AppleClient a = new AppleClient();
   try{
      // will throw exception
      a.set();
   }
   // How do I know that this method will throw the following exception?
   catch(FaultException<DivideByZeroException> ex){}
```

Is it possible to know what exceptions can be thrown by a service method, so that we can catch those exceptions? Looking at WSDL file I was able to understand the exceptions thrown by a method but is there any easier way to list the methods and exceptions that can be thrown by a method? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web.config, there is a behavior tag. Place the following config.

```
<behavior>
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" /></behavior>
```

If you want to trace all service calls, you can paste the following to your config file of your wcf. initializeData is the location the log file be written to. You need to use the [service trace viewer tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/service-trace-viewer-tool-svctraceviewer-exe) to view the log.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning" propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="myUserTraceSource" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\logs\Traces.svclog" />
</sharedListeners>
```